# Pop up com Bootstrap ao carregar página

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Como posso fazer com que abra um pop up do Bootstrap ao carregar a página?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deveria funcionar assim, é assim que tenho. Estás a importar o JS do Bootstrap?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primeiro aplique um ID ao modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aí em tags `<script></script>` coloque:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Simplesmente perfeito obrigado